# type conversion when using pointers in arguments

Tags: c, pointers, printf

Here's the code

```
void test(char *bar) {
    printf("%s", bar);
}

int main(int x, char *argv[]) {
    test(argv[0])
    return 0;
}
```

`argv[]` is an array of pointers, and `argv[0]` gets the first pointer in the array.

When used in `test(char *whatever)`, because it's a pointer, I thought it would print the memory address, NOT the value. (to get the value, you would `printf("%s,*whatever)`

Is there a type conversion going on? Am I misunderstanding how pointers work?

Comment: `%s` expects an argument of  `char *` type to print the null terminating string it points to.

Comment: `bar` is of type `char*`, so `*bar` would be a `char`. It even rhymes.

Comment: Conner case: OP's thought about printing the address applies to an _object_ pointer like `char *bar` and `printf("%p\n", (void*) some_object_pointer);` is a good way to do that.  If the pointer was to a _function_, `printf("%p\n", (void*) some_function_pointer);` is not specified to "work".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `%s` format specifier to `printf` expects a pointer to a string (i.e. the address of the first element of an array of characters ending with a null byte) and prints that string.

If you want to print a pointer value, use the `%p` format specifier.

```
printf("%p", (void *)bar);
```

Note that the cast to `void *` pointer is required here, one of the few times such a cast is needed.

Comment: What is a not-null terminated _string_? :)

Comment: @SouravGhosh a segfault waiting to happen ;)

Comment: @UnknowableIneffable Yes, or ... perhaps not.

Comment: @UnknowableIneffable ummm... I doubt that, because there exist nothing called a _string_ which is not null-terminated, so a non-existant code produces no binary that can segfault. :P

Comment: @SouravGhosh got me there.

Comment: thank you! casting it to void* or not shows no difference. is there a reason why it's required?

Comment: @user8255253 yes, because the standard mandates so (see below answer, disclaimer: it's by me). `printf()` is a variadic function and there exist no default argument promotion for pointers, so to be standard conforming, you must cast the argument to `void *`.

Comment: @Sourav  a null terminated string is some like   's' 't' 'r' '\0'

Answer (score 3):

No, you got it wrong, `%s` conversion specifier needs the address of the first element of a null-terminated character array and prints the content of the array until it finds a null terminator.

Quoting `C11` chapter §7.21.6.1

> `s`
>
> If no `l` length modifier is present, the argument shall be a pointer to the initial
>   element of an array of character type.280) Characters from the array are
>   written up to (but not including) the terminating null character. [....]

Indeed, if you want to print an address, you must

- use `%p` conversion specifier
- cast the argument to `void *`.

Reference, same chapter,

> `p`
>
> The argument shall be a pointer to `void`. The value of the pointer is
>   converted to a sequence of printing characters, in an implementation-defined
>   manner.

---

<sup>In this specific case, the argument being a pointer to char and as mentioned in chapter §6.2.5, a pointer to void and a pointer to character type having the same representation and alignment requirements, it is interchangeable here and the cast is not a must, but in case of pointer to other types (non-compatible) must have the cast there</sup>

Comment: Concerning "... to print the address, you must  .... cast the argument to `void *` and "A pointer to `void` shall have the same representation and alignment requirements as a pointer to a character type." C11 §6.2.5 28 and its footnote "meant to imply interchangeability".  This certainly seems to imply the `void*` cast (a good idea) is not a _must_ in this situation given they have the same representation and thus indistinguishable.

Comment: @chux Yes, for a character pointer, you are very right. But in general, it does not hold good for all other types, no? So, thought not a MUST in this case, it'll be required in other cases, and is redundant but does no harm either, in this case, I'll update.

Comment: @chux Edited, hopes this clarifies any confusion. :)

Answer (score 0):

The `"%s"` needs a pointer as parameter. It would start reading from the pointer's value until it finds a `'\0'` and it goes one character at a time.

So it requires an address but it does not print the address, it prints the string that is where the pointer points to.

Answer (score 0):

A pointer **is** a variable which **contains** a memory address. So, if you want to print the memory  address, you need to print a value which such a variable contains. You can use any numeric formatting in printf to do so, however there is the special one for pointers: `%p`. it is a portable way to cast it to `(void*)` though it is not needed on most systems.

when you use something like `*pointer` you ask the compiler to get the first value in memory pointed by this pointer. The type of the result depends on what is the pointer pointing to. So, in `char *pointer` the operation will return a single char. It would be absolutely equivalent to `pointer[0]`. So, in your example `printf("%s", *whatever)` will probably crash, because you the printf will try to interpret the value of the first character as an address of a string. However, you could print this character as the following: `printf("%c", *whatever)`